# How to create multi-regional website using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a multi-regional website using WordPress. i'm working on url http://localhost/siteone I want when someone come from usa redirect to the localhost/siteone/usa/
I edit the function.php file of wordpress theme with code below, but getting error the url become localhost/siteone/usa/usa/usa/usa

```
// Detacting user location using ipstack

$json = file_get_contents('http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=ACCESSKEY&language=en');
// Converts it into a PHP object
$data = json_decode($json);
$loc = $data->country_code;
//NA = northamerica
//End of Decating user location     
if($loc=="NA"){      header("Location: usa/");      }
```

This works very well sidealone but when I add in function.php in theme file not working and give me a error. what should I do. Should i use some session or anything eles.

Comment: There are few ways to achieve that - you may try in JS using: navigator.language and then do redirect - but it's not best method sometimes user have en-US lang even if it's not true. Best would be geoip function in PHP to check from where somes request, than response with language specific route. Alternatively do as many big websites do - landing page is language settings, than it's stored eg. inside local storage.

Comment: I don't understand the last point please can you explain it a little bit or give a suggestion of any article

Comment: previously nvidia.com had this kind of solution - after going to route `/` first you had to choose your language, but for some reason currently it's picked for you automaticly. I can't remember other good example of this solution.

Comment: how they do that?

Comment: This is fully frontend solution. Once user choses own language website saves variable like this -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage user is redirected with JS to language specific route. Since language var is set on every page eg. contacts / home page etc. JS checks for this variable and simply serves lang specific content (this can be done without reload).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's trying to redirect multiple times, since it'll check the person's location, then redirect, then after redirecting it'll check again, and redirect again, etc.

What you could do is check whether "/usa" is already in the page URL, and if not, redirect, something like this could work:

```
if ($loc === "NA" && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'usa/') === false) {
    header("Location: usa/");
}
```

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is the URL of the current page, not including the domain.

Comment: why to use === instead of ==, and I add this on function.php it is not working(not redirecting the url)

Comment: @Shani it's good practice to use === where you can and it's faster - you can test it in some loop.

Comment: I add this on function.php it is not working(not redirecting the url)

Comment: Does $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] show you the correct URL for the page? echo it and see what you get. If it's not returning the correct URL, you'll need to solve that issue first, or use another way to get the current page's URL.

Answer (score 1):

For languages and create diferents regionals website, I'd recommend you this plugins (pro):

- https://polylang.pro/ (just one paid)
- [enter link description here](https://wpml.org/es/) (anual fee)

Custom code based on language:

```
<?php 
                if(pll_current_language() == 'en') {
                    echo 'Only in english';
                } else if(pll_current_language() == 'fr') {
                    echo 'Seulment en francais'; 
                }  
        ?>
```

If you prefer control language throught web server, use better: *$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']*

Link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php

Regards!

Comment: `echo echo` are you sure?

Comment: @Zydnar that was a mistake ;)